# Analyse the Singleton Pattern in JVM which was constructed as a constant

Tags: java, design-patterns, jvm

I want to use Singleton Pattern by this way:

```
    public static final XXX INSTANCE = new XXX();

    private XXX() {}
```

Can you analyse the consequence from the perspective in JVM?

Comment: Did you try it?  Did you run into any problems?

Comment: Nope. Only problem is you won't be able to lazy load it. But that's not necessary for most objects.

Comment: In addition to the multi-threading issues mentioned below, be aware that in Java, it's possible for the same class to be loaded multiple times in the same VM (for example, in separate WARs in a web server, if the class isn't present in the server's classpath). Singletons in Java cannot be guaranteed to be such, so be careful what you use them for.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is this singleton design pattern correct?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14890717/is-this-singleton-design-pattern-correct)

Comment: I would use an `enum` with one instance.

Answer (score 2):

You may run into problems if you have a multi-threaded application.  This post may be of assistance. [Thread Safe Singleton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6088195/factory-for-thread-safe-singleton-in-java)

Comment: Hogwash. The static constant will be initialized at class-load time, long before any user threads are running.

Comment: @amalloy: threads?  Do you mean to suggest that this pattern is thread safe?  If so, this would be true if and only if the value is immutable.

Comment: Obviously if he attempts to call mutator methods from multiple threads after constructing the singleton, he will run into problems, just like with threaded access to any object. But the question was about initializing it, and since he does not attempt to lazy-load it, tkcsam's mention of threads is irrelevant.

Answer (score 2):

Initializing singletons as final static fields is safe.  You need to keep in mind that while the construct itself is thread-safe, it does not strengthen the safety of the code within.

Sometimes singletons are the correct solution to a problem, but I would encourage you to stay away from them in general.  [It makes usually testing harder, if nothing else.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/137975/what-is-so-bad-about-singletons)